# Dual Catagory Surface Chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface

I'm attempting to create a [surface chart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_charts/excel_charts_surface.htm) in python that will display 2 sets of categorised data from tests I have carried out. The table is in the form of:

```
        |0000|0001|0010|0011
    0000| 301| 143| 145| 360
    0001| 283| 153|  84| 295
    0010| 227| 139| 108| 337
    0011| 250| 147| 143| 458
```

I would like to make it into something much like this graph produced in excel: [image: graph produced in excel]

However, I am struggling doing that with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Is there any particular detail that you are struggling with, or don't you know at all where to start from? Also, what format is your data in?

Comment: so far have tried the tutorial at https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html. my data is in the format of arrays, but this can be changed if nessassary. e.g 0000 = []

Comment: If you have gone through that tutorial, you must have some code already -- it would be much easier for everybody if you would post that code here and any error messages you possibly get.